# Extracting arguments from a list of function calls

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have some list like the following form

$ \{ j[two, 1,1,1,1], j[two,2,2,2,2], j[two,3,3,3,3] \}$

```
list = {j[two, 1, 1, 1, 1], j[two, 2, 2, 2, 2], j[two, 3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

I want to change this list into the form

$\{ \{two, \{1,1,1,1\} \}, \{two, \{2,2,2,2\}\}, \{two, \{3,3,3,3\}\}$

For the individual, I can do this by

```
 List@@j[two,List[1,1,1,1]]
```

But I want to deal with the whole $ \{ j[two, 1,1,1,1], j[two,2,2,2,2], j[two,3,3,3,3] \}$  and obtain the desired results

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

```
g = {#, {##2}} &;
```

#### 1.

```
g @@@ list
```

> ```
> {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}}
> ```

#### 2.

```
list /. j -> g
```

> ```
> {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}}
> ```

#### 3.

```
Block[{j = g}, list]
```

> ```
> {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}}
> ```

#### 4.

```
With[{j = g}, Evaluate @ list]
```

> ```
> {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {j[two, 1, 1, 1, 1], j[two, 2, 2, 2, 2], j[two, 3, 3, 3, 3]}

{First@#, List @@ Rest@#} & /@ list
```

> {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}}

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {j[two, 1, 1, 1, 1], j[two, 2, 2, 2, 2], j[two, 3, 3, 3, 3]}

list /. j[x__] :> {First[{x}], Rest[{x}]}
```

Comment: Also `list /. j[x_, y__] :> {x, {y}}`

Comment: Shoot that was even better

Answer (score 5):

```
Cases[list,j[x_,y__]:> {x,{y}}]

(* {{two, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {two, {2, 2, 2, 2}}, {two, {3, 3, 3, 3}}} *)
```